# How do I get iWeb to use a Google Webfont?

Tags: fonts, iweb

How do I get iWeb to use a font from [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to edit the code after iWeb generates it. Webfonts needs a link in the head so that the browser knows to download the font, and the CSS selector that you want to apply the font to needs modifying. (Google gives all the instructions)

Although even if you did this it would require doing every time the site was updated as iWeb would just write over your code edits.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wyodor.net/Tutorials/Google/Google_Fonts.html

Comment: The mentioned site is down!